# Matching 2 characters following a certain set of characters, but not matching anything in that set

Tags: regex, markdown, sublimetext, oniguruma

I'm working on improving Github-Flavored Markdown syntax highlighting in Sublime Text, which uses the Oniguruma regex engine. Specifically, I'm trying to improve the matching of `**bold**`/`__bold__` sections. Since working with regexes in `.tmLanguage` XML files is a PITA, I'm using [`PackageDev`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageDev) and its [`.YAML-tmLanguage`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html#file-format) format. Here is the original regex:

```
name: markup.bold.markdown
begin: (?x)(?:^|\s|\G)(\*\*|__)(?=\S)(?=(<[^>]*+>| (?<raw>`+)([^`]|(?!(?<!`)\k<raw>(?!`))`)*+\k<raw>|
  \\[\\`*_{}\[\]()#.!+\->]?+| \[((?<square>[^\[\]\\]| \\.| \[ \g<square>*+ \])*+\](([ ]?\[[^\]]*+\])| (\([ \t]*+<?
    (.*?)>?[ \t]*+((?<title>['"])(.*?)\k<title>)?\))))|(?!(?<=\S)\1).)++(?<=\S)\1)
end: (?<=\S)(\1)
captures:
  '1': {name: punctuation.definition.bold.markdown}
```

and here's an [example](https://regex101.com/r/iX2wZ8/1).

This works fine in a regular sentence:

```
I want this word to be **bold** but not this.
```

but not when the bolded text is immediately preceded by a paren, bracket, or brace:

```
I like bold (**like this**) but it isn't!
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/iX2wZ8/2)

So, I figured I'd add `(`, `[`, and `{` to the first group:

```
begin: (?x)(?:^|\s|\G|[\(\[\{])...
```

but [this](https://regex101.com/r/iX2wZ8/3) happens - the paren/bracket/brace is matched, causing problems with highlighting:

Current behavior:

[image: current]

With new regex:

[image: new]

As you can see, the opening paren is highlighted, when it shouldn't be.

So, my question is: How should I alter things so that the opening paren is not highlighted, but the desired text is?

Comment: Your current regex failed to highlight the text present inside **

Comment: You mean this https://regex101.com/r/iX2wZ8/4 ?

Comment: I'm asking you only. It would be better if you reply me.

Comment: @Avinash sorry about the delay, I had a meeting. I'm not sure what you mean by "failed to highlight the text...". It only matches the final letter on regex101, but in Sublime it works fine, as you can see in the first image. I tried your version 4, but now nothing is highlighted bold - ` this is **bold** text` or `this is (**parenthetical**) text`.